# Redmine: Make "Spent time" field required for each comment on issue

Tags: redmine, redmine-plugins

Me and my co-workers often forget to set spent time on redmine issue.

Is there any way to make "spent time" field required, when changing any issue data?

Answer (score 0):

Spent time in issues is not field for manual filling, it's calculating field.

Its value is a sum of spent times (not field but entity) created for issue.

You can fill spent times fields instead issue field - spent time already has date, spent hours and comment fields. Additionally you can add custom fields for spent time.

It's all available without plugins.

But if you want to include spent time info besides time and change issue behavior, you have to do some development work - add new calculated fields to issue etc.

Comment: When editing an issueyou can add issue comment, change status ets, and also also add new spent time entry  (with enabled time tracking option in project) in one place. It's very comfortable workflow, but without required flag easy to forget set spent time value. I am looking for way to adding requied flag to field in "Log time" fieldset (https://goo.gl/bTTevK)

Comment: Huh, then you can patch ```IssuesController```, method ```update```.
There you can check ```params[:time_entry]```, and return client to edit page if neccesary values are missed.
Are you familiar with redmine plugins development?